# DPY-6005:cannot connect to database.Connection failed with"[WinError 10061]No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

```
# Program to perform CRUD operations on student data using oracledb.

import oracledb
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ['Pin number', 'Name', 'Branch']
conn = oracledb.connect(user = 'UserID', password = '********', dsn = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9500/apex')
StudetNotFound = 'Student not found!'
InsertQuery = f"INSERT INTO Students VALUES(?, ?, ?);"
SelectStudentQuery = f"SELECT * from Students where Pin = ?;"
UpadateNameQuery = f"UPDATE Students set Name = ? where Pin = ?;"
UpadateBranchQuery = f"UPDATE Students set Branch = ? where Pin = ?;"
SelectAllStudentsQuery = "SELECT *from Students;"
RemoveStudentQuery = f"DELETE from Students where Pin = ?;"
SortByNameQuery = "SELECT Pin, Name, Branch from Students ORDER     BY Name;"

def AddStudent():
    Pin = int(input('Enter Pin: '))
    Name = input('Enter student name: ')
    Branch = input('Enter Branch: ')
    conn.execute(InsertQuery, (Pin, Name, Branch));
    conn.commit()
    print("Records created successfully")

def CheckPin(Pin):
    if(list(conn.execute(SelectStudentQuery, (Pin, ))) != []):
        return
    else:
        Pin = 0

def ReadPin():
    Pin = int(input('Enter Pin: '))
    return Pin

def ShowAll():
    table = list(conn.execute(SelectAllStudentsQuery))
    print(tabulate(table, headers = headers, tablefmt = 'grid'))

def UpdateDetails():
    Pin = ReadPin()
    if Pin != 0:
        Name = input('Enter name: ') 
        Branch = input('Enter Branch: ')
        conn.execute(SelectStudentQuery)
        cursor = conn.execute(UpadateNameQuery, (Name, Pin))
        cursor = conn.execute(UpadateBranchQuery, (Branch, Pin))
        conn.commit()
        return
    print(StudetNotFound)

def SearchStudent():
    Pin = ReadPin()
    if Pin != 0:
        table = list(conn.execute(SelectStudentQuery, (Pin, )))
        print(tabulate(table, headers = headers, tablefmt = 'grid'))
        return
    print(StudetNotFound)

def RemoveStudent():
    Pin = ReadPin()
    if Pin != 0:
        table = list(conn.execute(RemoveStudentQuery, (Pin, )))
        conn.commit()
        print('Student details removed successfully!')
        return
    print(StudetNotFound)

def SortByName():
    table = list(conn.execute(SortByNameQuery))
    print(tabulate(table, headers = headers, tablefmt = 'grid'))

def quit():
    conn.close()
    exit()

menu = [AddStudent, ShowAll, UpdateDetails, SearchStudent, SortByName, RemoveStudent, quit]

def main():
    while 1:
        print('\n1. Add Student')
        print('2. Show all')
        print('3. Update Details')
        print('4. Search')
        print('5. SortByName')
        print('6. RemoveStudent')
        print('7. Exit')
        try:
            menu[int(input('Enter your choice: ')) - 1]()
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            print('Please enter a valid option!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a problem with these client and server code, I keep getting the [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I am running administrator server in another system and trying to connect with it. It tried using *dns* paramter but it is not working and tried turning off my system's firewall off for sometime but it did not work.

The error is like this:

```
')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 1013, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 135, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 318, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 206, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 177, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 109, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\errors.py", line 111, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
```

Comment: Assuming the address and port (9500?) are correct, is the listener running on that remote server, and does that (or the network) have a firewall that might be block it? (You said "tried turning off my system's firewall" but it's unclear if that was on the client or server, or both; and there could be something in between.)

Comment: I agree '9500/apex' looks like it is not the database port and service name for normal SQL access.  I would expect something like '1521/orclpdb1' or '1521/xepdb1'

Comment: Yes, It worked successfully, thank you!